# clash betwenn doclicense and hyperref

Tags: latex, hyperref

I recently updated Miktex packages, and now have an error
*Package hyperxmp Error: hyperref must be loaded before hyperxmp.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-nc-sa},
    version={4.0},
]{doclicense}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `pdftex` option.

Answer (score 1):

Placing hyperref before doclicense fixes the problem